# How to use Multiprocessing effeciently with pytube library in python for quicker downloads?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am using python and the pytube library to download videos given a playlist link on youtube. This is what I came up with:

```
import pytube

playlist = pytube.Playlist(youtube_playlist_link)

for video in playlist.videos:
    pytube.query.StreamQuery.get_by_itag(video.streams,itag=251).download(output_path=r'C:\Users\Anderson\OneDrive\Desktop\Vids')
```

It took over one minute to download 12 audio streams which is way slower than my internet speed. I tried using async but I don't think it works with the library so I switched to muliprocessing.

```
import pytube
from multiprocessing import Process

yt = pytube.Playlist(youtube_playlist_link)

def first_half(): 
    for video in range(0,7,1):
        #Downloads first half of playlist audio
        x = yt.video_urls[video]
        y = pytube.YouTube(x)
        pytube.query.StreamQuery.get_by_itag(y.streams, itag=251).download(output_path=r'C:\Users\Anderson\OneDrive\Desktop\Vids')

def second_half():
    for video in range(7,12,1):
        #Download second half of playlist audio

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fh = Process(target=first_half)
    sh = Process(target=second_half)
    fh.start()
    sh.start()
    fh.join()
    sh.join()
```

This more than halved my previous one minute but is inefficient to make.

If I have 4 more cores in my CPU is there a way I can use them to download audio without having to make a new function for each? All six cores would split up the 12 songs evenly with one function downloading them all.

---

Also, I'm new to `async` so if I used `async` would I implement like this?

```python
import pytube
import asyncio

playlist = pytube.Playlist(playlist_link)

async def main():
    for video in playlist.videos:
        await pytube.query.StreamQuery.get_by_itag(video.streams, itag=251).download(output_path=r'C:\Users\Anderson\OneDrive\Desktop\Vids')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Does the library need to support `async` for me to use it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async` approach would be best, or perhaps some combination of `async` and `multiprocessing`, since this primarily involves network and disk IO.

But I'm not familiar with `pytube` or `async-pytube` so I'll just address not having to create a new function for each CPU core.

```python
import pytube
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Process
import os


yt = pytube.Playlist(youtube_playlist_link)

def download_vids(id: int, start: int, end: int):
    for video in range(start, end, 1):
        print(f'[{id}] - downloading video', video)

        x = yt.video_urls[video]
        y = pytube.YouTube(x)
        pytube.query.StreamQuery.get_by_itag(y.streams, itag=251).download(output_path=r'C:\Users\Anderson\OneDrive\Desktop\Vids')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CPU_COUNT = cpu_count()

    # better than cpu_count but only supported on some *nix distros
    try:
        CPU_COUNT = len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    NUM_VIDS = len(yt.video_urls)
    
    print('CPU COUNT: ', CPU_COUNT)
    print('NUM VIDS: ', NUM_VIDS)
    print()

    start_end = []
    step, rem = divmod(NUM_VIDS, CPU_COUNT)
    off = 0

    # evenly distribute downloads amongst processes
    for i in range(CPU_COUNT):
        start = i * step + off
        end = start + step
        if rem > 0:
            off += 1
            end += 1
        
        start_end.append({'start': start, 'end': end})
        rem -= 1


    # create processes
    procs: list[Process] = []
    for i in range(CPU_COUNT):
        proc = Process(target=download_vids, kwargs=dict(id=i, **start_end[i]))
        procs.append(proc)

    # start processes
    for i, proc in enumerate(procs):
        proc.start()
        print('-- started process:', i)

    # join processes
    for i, proc in enumerate(procs):
        proc.join()
        print('-- joined process:', i)
```

Comment: @Anderson I edited your question and added your comment. I'm editing my answer to address your new questions now. Do you mind accepting my answer in the meantime?